# Addition problem, "integers" acting like strings

Tags: javascript

```
    var 
        calculator = document.calculator;
            input1 = calculator.input1;
            input2 = calculator.input2;
            result = calculator.result;
            equals = calculator.equals;

    function add(a,b) {
     equals.value = a+b;
    }

    result.addEventListener("click", function() {
     add.apply(add, [input1.value, input2.value]);   
    });

<form name="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="input1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" /><br />
    <input type="button" name="result" value="result" /><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="equals" readonly="true" />
</form>
```

It only returns the to numbers together -- not added. For example: 5 + 3 = 53 not 8.
How do I fix this??

Comment: You'll never get 5+3=7.  You could get 4+3=7, or 5+2=7.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)` if it's a float type or `parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10)` for integer type.

Comment: Also use `isNaN()` to handle non numeric values.

Comment: Number(a) + Number(b) generalizes that

Comment: Should specify radix on parseInt().

Answer (score 3):

Javascript will, by default, always interpret input as strings.

There are a few ways around this, by using the builtin parseXXX() functions or simply by first multiplying the values by 1 as recommended by this [page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, your code is doing a string concat operation (using `+` on strings) on `a` and `b`.

You need to explicitly specify that, you want addition (using `+` on numbers) to be performed on `a` and `b`.

Change your add function to:

```
function add(a,b) {
     equals.value = Number(a) + Number(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler.

Just multiply the values of each input by 1 to convert them to number.

```
input1 = calculator.input1*1;
input2 = calculator.input2*1;
```

or subtract a zero

```
input1 = calculator.input1-0;
input2 = calculator.input2-0;
```

Note: Thanks Matthew for the tip ;)

Comment: Adding zero will have the same problem, except he'd end up with "5030". *Subtracting* zero would work though.