# Strange behavior when dividing inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a basic application to learn more, but have came across an issue.

I have 3 input boxes. people, bill, tip. the maths is as follows:

(bill + tip) / people. When i try to divide in my code it seems to add onto the end of my total.

So far i have this. http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/a8eJT/

```
    var updateTotal = function () {
      var people = parseInt($('#people').val());
      var bill = ($('#bill').val());
      var tip = ($('#tip').val());
      var billTip = bill + tip;
      var billTipPeople = billTip / people;




      $('#total').text("£" + billTipPeople)
```

If i could get pointed in the right direction that would be great :)

Comment: `bill + tip` will perform string concatenation, not addition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Addition problem, "integers" acting like strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368443/addition-problem-integers-acting-like-strings)

Comment: var billTip = parseInt(bill) + parseInt(tip);
or
parseFloat(bill) + parseFloat(tip);

Comment: Check it http://jsfiddle.net/a8eJT/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close. I got it working like this

```
var updateTotal = function () {
  var people = parseInt($('#people').val(),10);
  var bill = parseFloat($('#bill').val());
  var tip = parseFloat($('#tip').val());
  var billTip = bill + tip;
  var billTipPeople = billTip / people;
  if (isNaN(billTipPeople)) billTipPeople = 0; // output zero if NaN

  $('#total').text("£" + billTipPeople.toFixed(2))
```

The issue is that javascript has some weird rules about string concatenation. "1"+"1" == "11". You need to be explicit every time.

**parseInt GOTCHA**: ALWAYS use the second (optional) *base* parameter of parseInt. Values like "015" will be parsed as octal into the decimal number 13 otherwise. Hence the popular joke, "Why do programmers confuse Halloween and Christmas? Because OCT31 == DEC25!"

Comment: Thanks Joe, Totally unrelated how would i get the NaN (Not-a-Number) to show as £0?

Comment: @Ma9ic: You can test for it explicitly: `"£" + isNaN(billTipPeople) ? 0 : billTipPeople.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Updated the answer with something more clean than a ternary operator

Comment: @Ma9ic to get NaN to show as £0 check my answer below. Or have a look at this fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/a8eJT/11/

Answer (score 2):

`bill + tip` will perform string concatenation, not addition, because they are both string. At least one of the operands has to be a number if you want to perform addition.

While `parseFloat` and `parseInt` work, using the [*unary plus* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) is shorter to write and you don't have to worry about the type of number:

```
var people = +$('#people').val();
var bill = +$('#bill').val();
var tip = +$('#tip').val();
```

This works as long as the input value only consists of a number. But if the input only *starts* with a number, e.g. `"5 foo"` and you want to extract the number from the beginning of the string, you really have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 1):

Your **bill** and **tip** variables are strings. Try using **parseFloat()**. Using the addition sign (**+**) on two strings will simply concatenate them.

```
var bill = parseFloat($('#bill').val());
var tip = parseFloat($('#tip').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

While you used **parseInt()** in one case, why didn't you follow same path in similar situations?

Anyway, here's how I have modified your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input#bill, input#tip').blur(function () {
    var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return;
    }
    var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(cleanNum);
    if (num / cleanNum < 1) {}
});

$('#people, #bill, #tip').keyup(function () {
    updateTotal();
});



var updateTotal = function () {
    var people = parseInt($('#people').val());
    if (isNaN(people) || people === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var bill = parseFloat($('#bill').val());
    if (isNaN(bill)) {
        bill = 0;
    }
    var tip = parseFloat($('#tip').val());
    if (isNaN(tip)) {
        tip = 0;
    }
    var billTip = bill + tip;
    var billTipPeople = billTip / people;

    $('#total').text("£" + billTipPeople);
    // round up to 2 d.p. like below:
    // $('#total').text("£" + billTipPeople.toFixed(2));
};
```

});

To save you from coming back again and asking why your app has decided to come up another crazy behaviour, I've added the following checks:

When user enters number of people, even though we are not ready to enter **total cost of bill**, it is updated as NaN. We prevent this nasty behaviour by...

```
if (isNaN(num)) {
    return;
}
```

We take same precaution in the **updateTotal()** function. Moreover, **watch out for division by 0!*** I give tips onle when I'm with my gf, otherwise, a person like me will break your app...

```
if (isNaN(people) || people === 0) {
    return;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8eJT/11/) >> http://jsfiddle.net/a8eJT/11/

Comment: Thanks dude but i noticed that the output at the end doesn't round up to 2 decimals.

Comment: @Ma9ic you should change the billTipPeople with billTipPeople.toFixed(2) in the last line. Finally, consider upvoting my answer if you find it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` in javascript.When you did with out using these then it will treat as strings.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var updateTotal = function () {
      var people = parseInt($('#people').val());
      var bill = parseInt($('#bill').val());
      var tip = parseInt($('#tip').val());
      var billTip = bill + tip;
      var billTipPeople = billTip / people;

      $('#total').text("£" + billTipPeople)
```

I have added parseint to both `bill` & `tip`

Comment: Who says the bill and tip are ints?

Comment: The spinner in the fiddle increments it by 1. :) but it could be float as x.xx is there. `parseFloat()` is a better choice.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice the spinner. Maybe that's another mistake, the spinner should be on the "number of people" box and not on the others